# bulk insert new row and if certain entry exists then update that row using a combination of two fields(no primary key) in PostgresDB using sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

so **rowObject** is an array of objects.
I want to insert the new entry but if a particular combination of fields of rows already in the db then updates that entry.

For example:- my array object is something like this

```
const rowObject= [

{code:"code1", date: "2021-05-13", value:23, point:4},

{code:"code2", date: "2021-05-13", value:24, point:4},

{code:"code2", date: "2021-07-10", value:25, point:4}

]
```

I want to bulk insert the rows but if a certain row has a combination of *code*  and *date* is there then update

ex-  if  **{code: "code2", date: "2021-05-13"}** already exists in the db then update the **value** and **point** of that row in the db else insert new rows.

```
const SRR = require("../models/srr.model");

SRR.bulkCreate(rowObject)
  .then((data) => {
    if (data[1].dataValues) {
       res.send({ msg: "Successfully Added To Db" });
    } else {
        res.send({ msg: "Error Adding To Db" });
    }
  })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
      res.send({ msg: "Error Adding To Db" });
   });
```

I tried **upsert** and **updateOnDuplicate: true** but its not working for me.
can anybody help me here.